# Icontact api - get all contacts from list

Tags: php, icontact

I am using the icontact php api. I want to get the last contact who entered the list so in the icontact api php I have this:

```
<php
public function getContacts() {
    // Make the call and return the data
    return $this->makeCall("/a/{$this->setAccountId()} /c/{$this->setClientFolderId()}/contacts?listId=49626&status=total&createDate=2015-02-16&createDateSearchType=gt", 'GET');
}
?>
```

than I use this to call it:

```
<?php
$oiContact = iContactApi::getInstance();

try {

var_dump($oiContact->getContacts());

 } catch (Exception $oException) { // Catch any exceptions

var_dump($oiContact->getErrors());

 }

 $obj = $oiContact->getLastResponse();

 $data = json_decode($obj,TRUE);
  echo $data['contacts'][0]['email'];
  echo $data['contacts'][0]['commitmentscore'];
  echo $data['contacts'][0]['firstName'];
  echo $data['contacts'][0]['phone'];
  ?>
```

It keeps giving me the same contact it is because the 0 in the echo but how can I make that a variable or an if condition just not sure how

paste bins with full code

http://pastebin.com/SBf73UNb //call
http://pastebin.com/CuGcCvU1 //api

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
/contacts?listId=49626&orderby=createDate:desc&limit=1", 'GET');
```

Got it from this page

http://www.icontact.com/developerportal/documentation/advanced-users/

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use orderby option,

check this [link](http://www.icontact.com/developerportal/documentation/contacts/)

sample they used

```
Get all contacts on a list ordered by First Name    GET https://app.sandbox.icontact.com/icp/a/<accountId>/c/<clientFolderId>/contacts?orderby=firstName
```

Instead of `firstname` you can use date, something like normal `SQL` query doing then fetch only first contact.

Also the return data will be always array so you have to run within a `foreach` for iterate the data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I wanted to make that create date a timestamp of now how would I do that **createDate  timestamp (in ISO8601 format)  Indicates the date on which the contact was added to iContact  2009-06-18 22:39:54**